# Limiting query results based upon data returned in the same query?

Tags: sql, oracle

Apologies in advance if this is an easy solution but since I'm not sure what to call this I didn't have any luck trying to search for it.

Given the following example data:

```
ID, QUANTITY, Date
1,2,01-APR-16
1,1,02-APR-16
1,0,03-APR-16
1,1,04-APR-16
1,0,05-APR-16
1,1,06-APR-16
1,0,07-APR-16
```

I would like a query to return the ID of the item and the corresponding date when the quantity equals zero, **but only if there is a later date** where the quantity is greater than zero. So in the above example, the select would return

```
1,03-APR-16
1,05-APR-16
```

I'm learning and have learned a lot from this site but I'm not sure how to accomplish this one. I know how to do a basic select and how to use subqueries but it would seem in this case I need to pass a result from one row into a subquery for another? Thank you for any direction and again sorry for being a newbie. Also a quick link to how to show sample tables in a table format would be helpful, the advanced help doesn't show that part I'm probably looking in the wrong place. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your table is called t. I changed column name "date" to "dt" - don't use reserved Oracle words as column names.

```
with a as (select id, max(dt) max_dt from t where quantity > 0 group by id)
select id, dt from t join a using (id) where quantity = 0 and t.dt < a.max_dt
```

ADDED:  OP asked for an additional condition in a comment (below). This will answer that additional request.

OP (yes Mobilemike, that is you!): The idea is the same. With some practice you will be able to do it on our own. Note: I am deleting a record with quantity 0 only if the oldest record had the value 0 (I am not deleting the oldest record *with quantity zero* if it is not the absolute oldest record for that id!)

Good luck!

```
with a as (select id, max(dt) max_dt from t where quantity > 0 group by id),
     b as (select id, min(dt) min_dt group by id)
select id, dt from t join a using (id) join b using (id)
where quantity = 0 and t.dt < a.max_dt and t.dt != b.min_dt
```

Comment: This is an excellent example and has taught me a lot, I will use the 'with' statement often in my queries. Thank you.

Comment: How would this query be different if I wanted to exclude the first row with min(dt) if the qty was zero? I'm trying to find items that were in stock and subsequently went out of stock and were then restocked. Since all items are created with a qty of 0, I would want to exclude the first instance of a zero qty in my query.

Comment: Adding the answer to my original answer (no ability to have code in a comment, I believe)

Comment: Thank you again. This concept was a great thing to learn this morning.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using a subquery rather than a temporary table might look like

```
select t1.id, t1.dt from t t1, (select id, max(dt) max_dt from t where quantity>0 group by id)  t2
where  t1.id=t2.id and t1.dt < t2.max_dt and t1.quantity =0
```

I too changed the column names to match those given by mathguy.

UPDATE: I've changed the query to account for the IDs.

Comment: Hi dsp,   apparently you are not familiar with "subquery factoring." What I have in my solution is a subquery, it is just written in a "with clause"; Oracle processes it as if the subquery was written where "a" appears in the query. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2077142 In addition, in your solution you select the max(dt) over the entire table, which is OK only if all id's are the same; in my solution I allowed for the possibility of diverse id's in the table. That is why both my subquery and my join include id in them.

Comment: Also, your solution (in which you take max(dt) over all rows, not just those with quantity > 0) will give the incorrect result if the last two rows (by date) both have quantity = 0. Your query will not pick up the last one, but it will pick up the second-to-last, because its date is < max(dt).

Comment: Yes, I missed the 'later date where the quantity is greater than zero' part.Fixed.

Comment: Right - and now you ended up with the same solution as mine, except the use of subquery factoring. Please note the "with clause" has several benefits: ease of reading and maintaining (changes made in one place), no repeated code if you ever need to refer to the same query more than once, and also the optimizer MAY treat the "subquery" as a temp table if it finds that to be more efficient than treating it as a subquery.

Comment: Well, it's been a while since I used a with clause and that was in DB2, not Oracle. But the syntax is actually very easy and I just might use it more often in the future, given all the benefits you say it has over a subquery.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, I've learned a great deal from this exchange. I'm going to try mathguy's solution now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use analytics to solve this using a single read on your table:

```
with t as
(
  select 1 id, 2 QUANTITY, date'2016-04-01' dt from dual union all
  select 1 , 1 , date'2016-04-02' from dual union all
  select 1 , 0 , date'2016-04-03' from dual union all
  select 1 , 1 , date'2016-04-04' from dual union all
  select 1 , 0 , date'2016-04-05' from dual union all
  select 1 , 1 , date'2016-04-06' from dual union all
  select 1 , 0 , date'2016-04-07' from dual
)

select id, quantity, dt from (
  select id, quantity, t.dt, max( quantity ) over ( partition by id order by dt rows between current row and unbounded following ) nxt_qt
  from t
)
where quantity = 0 and nxt_qt > 0
order by 1, 3
```

Comment: I don't think this is done all in one read of the table... while only half the rows have been read, how would one know already what the max(quantity) is over rows between current row and unbounded following?

Comment: The window processing is done in memory. You can run a explain plan to check the table reads.